# How to get min value of a specific object array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a sample object array like this, I am trying to get the min quantity grouped by fruitname, can someone help me understand how to do this? I have tried using reduce , combined with map, but I can't seem to get the correct answer. So for example the expected result should be apple:11, strawberries:7, pear:33, plum:15, grapes:43

```
let fruits = [
{"sales date":"2022-09-03", "fruitname":"apple","unitprice":20, "quantity":19}
,{"sales date":"2022-09-03", "fruitname":"strawberries","unitprice":30, "quantity":20}
,{"sales date":"2022-09-03", "fruitname":"pear","unitprice":30, "quantity":33}
,{"sales date":"2022-09-03", "fruitname":"plum","unitprice":30, "quantity":65}
,{"sales date":"2022-09-03", "fruitname":"grapes","unitprice":30, "quantity":94}
,{"sales date":"2022-10-02", "fruitname":"apple","unitprice":30, "quantity":41}
,{"sales date":"2022-10-02", "fruitname":"strawberries","unitprice":30, "quantity":24}
,{"sales date":"2022-10-02", "fruitname":"pear","unitprice":30, "quantity":39}
,{"sales date":"2022-10-02", "fruitname":"plum","unitprice":30, "quantity":15}
,{"sales date":"2022-10-02", "fruitname":"grapes","unitprice":30, "quantity":44}
,{"sales date":"2022-06-23", "fruitname":"apple","unitprice":20, "quantity":11}
,{"sales date":"2022-06-23", "fruitname":"strawberries","unitprice":30, "quantity":7}
,{"sales date":"2022-06-23", "fruitname":"pear","unitprice":30, "quantity":53}
,{"sales date":"2022-06-23", "fruitname":"plum","unitprice":30, "quantity":75}
,{"sales date":"2022-06-23", "fruitname":"grapes","unitprice":30, "quantity":43}
];
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt at fixing this using reduce.

Comment: OP want all the sums, not a single value. Is that dupe the correct one?

Comment: @0stone0 the dupe still covers that case.